# Python: Function for Multiple Regression

Tags: python, pandas, function, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

import statsmodels.api as sm

Stock_Market = {'Year': [2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016],
                'Month': [12, 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                'Interest_Rate': [2.75,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.25,2.25,2.25,2,2,2,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75],
                'Unemployment_Rate': [5.3,5.3,5.3,5.3,5.4,5.6,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.9,6,5.9,5.8,6.1,6.2,6.1,6.1,6.1,5.9,6.2,6.2,6.1],
                'Stock_Index_Price': [1464,1394,1357,1293,1256,1254,1234,1195,1159,1167,1130,1075,1047,965,943,958,971,949,884,866,876,822,704,719]        
                }

df = pd.DataFrame(Stock_Market,columns=['Year','Month','Interest_Rate','Unemployment_Rate','Stock_Index_Price'])
```

Currently, I'm able to perform a multiple regression of 'Interest_Rate' & 'Unemployment_Rate' on 'Stock_Index_Price' using the following function:

```
def perform_regression_multiple(y, x1, x2=""):
    test = df[[y, x1, x2]].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    X = test[[x1, x2]]
    Y = test[[y]]
    
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X, Y)

    model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    predictions = model.predict(X) 

    print_model = model.summary()
    print(print_model)
    
#===========================================================================

perform_regression_multiple('Stock_Index_Price', 'Interest_Rate', 'Unemployment_Rate')
```

However, when I try to perform a linear regression (e.g. by using 'Interest_Rate' as the only explanatory variable) using the above function, then I receive the following error message:

```
perform_regression_multiple('Stock_Index_Price', 'Interest_Rate')
```

**KeyError: "[''] not in index"**

Obviously, both x1 and x2 need to be specified; otherwise it won't work. How am I supposed to modify the function in a way that allows me to specify the number of explanatory variables? The objective would be to extend the regression model by additional factors.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how you are defining your function:

```
def perform_regression_multiple(y, x1, x2=""):
```

And then how you are calling it:

```
perform_regression_multiple('Stock_Index_Price', 'Interest_Rate')
```

With that call, you are telling the function that `y="Stock Index Price"`, `x1="Interest Rate"` and `x2=""`, which is the default value.

On the very first line of your function, you are taking the x2 column:

```
test = df[[y, x1, x2]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

That you have defined as being "", and the error is saying that the column with name "" does not exist.

If you want to be able to perform a regression with one or two variables, make this:

```
def perform_regression_multiple(y, x1, x2=None):
    if x2:
        test = df[[y, x1, x2]].reset_index(drop=True)
    
        X = test[[x1, x2]]
    else:
        test = df[[y, x1]].reset_index(drop=True)
        
        X = test[[x1]]
    Y = test[[y]]
    
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X, Y)

    model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    predictions = model.predict(X) 

    print_model = model.summary()
    print(print_model)
```

You can leave the empty string as well and the `if` would still work the same way.

Even better, taking in account that for selecting columns in pandas and returing a dataframe you have to pass a list, you can do this, passing a list to the x_variables argument (even if it's a list of just one item):

```
def perform_regression_multiple(y: str, x_variables: list):
        columns = [y] + x_variables
        test = df[columns].reset_index(drop=True)
            
        X = test[x_variables]
        Y = test[[y]]
        
        regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        regr.fit(X, Y)
    
        model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
        predictions = model.predict(X) 
    
        print_model = model.summary()
        print(print_model)
```

Comment: Thank you Javier, works like a charm on my end! Another question: suppose I have 8 explanatory variables (i.e. x1, x2, x3, ...., x8). Is there a way to declare the condition in the same "short" fashion as above without having to specify the "if" command for each and every single variable?

Comment: Edited with the solution

Comment: Awesome stuff, just learned something new. Thanks again Javier - have a nice one ahead :)